# maven pom: difference between application.main.class and exec.main.class

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I've searched and read maven [docs](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html), but didn't find the answer. I'm new to java, so please forgive me if this is a duplication.

In our company project I see a pom defines such elements:

```
    <properties>
      <application.main.class>com.xxx.classfoo</application.main.class>
      <exec.main.class>com.yyy.classbar</exec.main.class>
      ...others...
    </properties>
```

So the question is what's the differences between them? Their names seem so much alike!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) :

> Maven properties are value placeholder, like properties in Ant. Their values are accessible anywhere within a POM by using the notation ${X}, where X is the property.

As described above they are just placeholders and can be referred to using ${propertyName} .

Now there may be need to refer to the classes defined by `application.main.class` or `exec.main.class` and that's why they are defined in proeprties and wherever to be used they can be referred using ${application.main.class} or ${exec.main.class}.

Comment: ahha, the placeholder names are really misleading ^_^.

Answer (score 1):

these are your custom properties defined specifically for your project - for more info: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties

try searching for `${application.main.class}` in your pom.xml and you will see where it is used